# How to detect calendar effects for stock prices (day-of-week, month, etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, delta

[x-post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420098/how-to-detect-calendar-effects-for-stock-prices-day-of-week-month-etc) from cross-validated:

This is a python/pandas question just as much as it is a statistical one.

How would I go about determining the typical delta for day-of-week and month effects of a given time series?

Taking the day-of-week effect as an example, so far I've written:

```
# Where `data` are close prices of a given symbol on a daily timeframe
# 1. Find change between prior day and given day
# 2. Group those changes by weekday
# 3. Find the mode (most common rate of change)
# 4. Normalize the weekday deltas to one another
deltas = data.diff().groupby(data.index.weekday).agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
delta_min = deltas.min()
dayofweek = 2 * ((delta - delta_min) / (delta.max() - delta_min)) - 1
```

I can already tell right off the bat that my code isn't accounting for monthly/yearly changes which is what I need help on (not accounting for these changes will skew the results). I also want to do this for month effects but I figure the solution will be similar to solving for day-of-week.

Comment: show us some data and expected output ?

Comment: some how I feel what you need is to create dummy variables to represent day of week, month, and fit a simple linear regression model. and the model coefficients should give you some information. but there is also the non-stationary property and "random" events. there are times market closes, or market close early, also days before and after holidays; or competitor IPOs...way too many variables that gives you noise.

Comment: I don't want to superimpose my idea of what the effect should be on the data, I'd rather it come about from the data itself like a moving average would. The contrast between the extremes is important. Yes, there are random events but with the size of the dataset I feel like that would be drowned out anyway. As for providing data, I don't feel like that is necessary as you can grab any timeseries data to work off of and it would be a valid working dataset.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more clear as to what I'm attempting to replicate; there have been many scholarly articles regarding day-of-week effect, monthly effect, holiday effect, etc. However I've never seen or perhaps am not astute enough to comprehend the mathematical formulas presented; I've only seen their results. I feel however that this is really just a basic question about how to group and process mode/mean between weekday, month and yearly data.